# How to concat all JS files in a folder and use SASS in GruntJS?

Tags: gruntjs

I have been trying this for sometime now. Each time I run `grunt` in my Terminal I get the following error:

```
User$: grunt
Loading "Gruntfile.js" tasks...ERROR
>> SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
Warning: Task "default" not found. Use --force to continue.

Aborted due to warnings.
```

This is my GruntFile.js

```
module.exports = function (grunt) { 

    grunt.initConfig({

        sass: {
            dist: {
                files: {
                    'css/css.css' : 'css/css.scss'
                }
            }
        },
        concat: {
            js: {
                src:['js/*.js'],
                dest: 'js/js.js'
            }
        },
        watch: {
            css: {
                files: '**/*.scss',
                tasks: ['sass']
            }
            js: {
                files: ['js/*.js'],
                tasks: ['concat:js']
            },
        }

    });

    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-concat');
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-sass');
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-watch');
    grunt.registerTask('default', ['watch', 'concat']);

};
```

My basic directory:

```
/js/jquery.js
/js/angular.js
/js/js.js
/css/settings.scss
/css/slider.scss
/css/css.css
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing a comma after your `watch:css` target (line 23).

Also, please note that the watch task never exits, so you want your default task to run it last:

```
grunt.registerTask('default', ['concat', 'watch']);
```

And finally, you should exclude your concatenated js from the list of watched files, to avoid looping.

```
module.exports = function (grunt) { 
  grunt.initConfig({
    sass: {
        dist: {
            files: {
                'css/css.css' : 'css/css.scss'
            }
        }
    },
    concat: {
        js: {
            src:['js/*.js', '!js/js.js'],
            dest: 'js/js.js'
        }
    },
    watch: {
        css: {
            files: 'css/*.scss',
            tasks: ['sass']
        },
        js: {
            files: ['js/*.js', '!js/js.js'],
            tasks: ['concat:js']
        },
    }
  });

  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-concat');
  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-sass');
  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-watch');

  grunt.registerTask('default', ['concat', 'watch']);
};
```

Comment: Done - please post your new error messages if you still get errors